# advanced Android menu

Tags: android, listview, menu

**Hi Everyone**

I'm new in android and i'd like to do a menu for an application.
I want to replicate the menu style of this game that has different section

http://i.giphy.com/l4Jz4PbvjJEZHZn8c.gif

I have 3 different xml layout that i want to show in my horizontal style menu **capable of swiping from a layout to another**.
I have heard i could use something called horizontal ListView but i don't really know how to use it.

How do i do?

Answer (score 0):

try Sliding tab Layout. Its the same function just need to edit the codes for different design